# Crear una instancia global de una clase?

Tags: java, jsp

Hola estoy creando un dinamic web project, usando una base de datos, el caso es que por motivos de velocidad y eficiencia quiero que la conexión a la base de datos (método getConnection) se haga sólo una vez en el momento que el cliente se conecta, para ello he creado una clase java cuyo constructor realiza el getConnection. En el index.jsp (primer jsp en ejecutarse), creo una instancia de dicha clase, logrando así conectarme a la base de datos, mi problema es que no sé como acceder a esa instancia desde otros jsp del webcontent.
¿Sabeis alguna manera de hacerlo?

Comment: Puedes usar el patron de diseño Singleton. Agrega el código que tienes hasta ahora para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Por otra parte, tu pregunta solo se refiere a Java y quizás a JSP. Por tal motivo he eliminado el resto de etiquetas que no tienen relación con la pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, he investigado el patrón singleton y lo he implementado con éxito :)

Comment: Si quieres agrega tu solución como respuesta y de paso ganas reputación. Saludos.